# How compute mortgage interest deduction for two mortgages that together exceed the max allowed indebtedness?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, tax-deduction

We have a mortgage for about $650k on our primary residence. It dates to 2012, i.e., to a period where $1M was the maximum allowable indebtedness. We also have a mortgage on a vacation home (which we don't rent out) for about $450k. It dates to 2018, hence falls under the rules limiting indebtedness to $750k. The interest rate is better on the loan for the primary residence, but because the loan balance is higher, we pay more total interest for that loan than for the loan on the vacation home. How do we compute the combined interest deduction for these loans?